# Is there any way to open a browser from different machine using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ip

I am just curious to know, is there any possibility to open/trigger a browser from different machine in same LAN using NodeJS.

I have gone through node's default 'http.createServer()' and browserSync. Using them I can create a server and open the page in other machine's. But dont know how to trigger the browser/tab automatically in them.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, but perhaps this will help... https://www.npmjs.com/package/open ?

Comment: thanks @dan75 . I will try to explain. lets say i have 2 computers A and B. I am working on computer A. I wanted to open some url in any browser of computer B, automatically.

Comment: So you have a machine B, & working on A. You will do nothing from A & in B a URL will be opened. Is that you want??

Comment: @JayadrathaMondal exactly!

Comment: Don't you think if it will be available then there will be a security issue? Even  I can open any tab in your browser now. Why do you need this?

Comment: @JayadrathaMondal I am sure there will be a security issue. but, what if there is some kind of Auth, through which I granted a access to computer A? I dont know how it can be done. There is no particular reason, I just thought how it would be if someone can able to trigger a browser from another machine or mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a massively over simplified solution to your problem, and as you're aware there are significant security considerations around this functionality.

However, using [`open`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open) this can be done quite easily on a local network (providing the correct firewall rules are in place).

**Computer B (the machine the browser should open on):**

```
var http = require('http');
var open = require("open");

function handleRequest(request, response){
    open("http://www.google.com", "firefox");
}

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

server.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:8080");
});
```

**Computer A (the machine to trigger the browser opening from):**

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: '<Computer A IP address>',
  port: 8080,
  path: '/'
};

http.request(options).end();
```

While running the code on computer B, if you run the computer A code then it should open Firefox at http://www.google.com on computer A.